# Can latency be avoided by using CAS in couchbase?

Tags: c#, nosql, couchbase

I am retrieving some data by means of `GetView`. But while performing some update operation i m getting latency. Can this be avoided using CAS or is there any other options available..

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific on what your doing and maybe include a code snippet?

Comment: I just need to perform some update operation. For example.. In my page if the user clicks like then his details should be updated in the couchbase bucket. I have tried my code.. for details pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190217/update-in-couchbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS is used to maintain consistency between  get and set operations. You can't reduce latency with CAS.

Comment: Fine.. Can CAS be used with GetView method?

Comment: It seems - no. You should use get methods - http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-net-1.2/api-reference-summary.html